# Complex structure multiple views in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am about to design one page in mvc which is very big. Below is structure.

```
Tab1
>> Sub tab1
>> Sub tab2
>> Sub tab3
>> Sub tab4
Tab2
Tab3
>> Sub tab1
Tab4
```

Single Save button.
So which would be best approach in above case? May I use partial or renderpartial? I also need to show above page with data filled. Everytime tab click should load sub tab views and informations? I am little confused on structure.

Comment: Could you add some code and maybe explain more clearly what is going to be in those tabs and what you are going to save.

Comment: There is nothing coded yet. I am about to create above structure in mvc. I need inputs/suggestion for above stuff and view rendering which I will need to do.

Comment: You should supply more details, how you are planning to achieve tab functionality and what is going to be inside it etc..

Comment: Since you are looking at a single save function, have you got any exposure on MVVM pattern and knockout.js library? MVVM patter will get you to define a client side viewmodel, to which you can keep on adding data on the fly, then you can implement a save method, which would post all the data back to the server in a single post. If you are not familiar with this concept, it will take a bit of a learning, but once you have the knowledge, it would really help you to simplify these sort of stuff